# Android - Get Location Only One Time

Tags: java, android, location

i need to get the current user location on an android app, so i've read some tutorials and samples on the web, but i see that in all the examples, the location is retrived from a "onLocationChange" that mean that every time the location change, the code in the "onLocationChange" is executed.

i need only to get the user location at the moment the app is started.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with LocationManager.[getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks for your answer, from your link seem that i need always to set a provider... is that right? have i to get the better provider and set it in the getLastKnownLocation?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to do.

Answer (score 15):

You can get the last know location using the code below. It gets the location providers and loops over the array backwards. i.e starts with GPS, if no GPS then gets network location. You can call this method whenever you need to get the location.

```
private double[] getGPS() {
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

/* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break                 out the loop*/
Location l = null;

for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
if (l != null) break;
}

double[] gps = new double[2];
if (l != null) {
gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
}
return gps;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting 0.0 for both lat and long, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator or actual device?

Comment: @Maurice, you get 0.0 cause Java auto sets the zero to variables. When l==null, then you get  gps = new double[2]; where all elements are zero :)

Comment: How can I call it on mainactivity ?

Answer (score 3):

use LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()

look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the main activity:

```
boolean bFirst = true;
function void onCreate(blabla) {
  if(bFirst) {
    //Do your stuff to get the location
    bFirst = false;
  }
}
```

Put the same in the onResume();

Comment: this make the code execute only one time, but the condition test is continuously probed

Comment: what a useless answer

Comment: @CaioComC Instead of just down-voting (an really old question), can you please explain why its a useless answer, and what can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

For the `getGPS()` method which Phobos proposed to work properly you have to allow access within your AndroidManifest.xml

That will get rid of your error of receiving 0.0

Add these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best location from all providers using this method.
First create a class which is called **FetchLocation**

```
public class FetchLocation implements LocationListener {
    private OnLocationFetchListner onLocationFetchListner;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void setOnLocationFetchListner(OnLocationFetchListner fetchListner, Context context) {
        this.onLocationFetchListner = fetchListner;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            onLocationFetchListner.OnFailed("PERMISSION DENIED");
            return;
        }
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Log.d("TAG", "BestProvider: " + provider);
        if (provider != null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 60 * 1000, 100, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
        } else {
            onLocationFetchListner.OnFailed("NO PROVIDERS");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationFetchListner.OnComplete(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }
}
```

Then you create a **OnLocationFetchListner** interface!

```
public interface OnLocationFetchListner {
    void OnComplete(Location location);
    void OnFailed(String e);
}
```

Then you can call this method anywhere in your code!

```
FetchLocation fetchLocation = new FetchLocation();
fetchLocation.setOnLocationFetchListner(new OnLocationFetchListner() {
    @Override
    public void OnComplete(Location location) {
        //do your work here
    }
}

    @Override
    public void OnFailed(String e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "OnFailed: "+e);
    }
}, context);
```

And the you have to add this in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```